# Write console output into a GUI

Tags: python

I am using pycharm IDE and have a script which makes a lot of tests.

The test results are printed into the console, which looks like this:

[image]

I have to do a lot of scrolling to check the results, there are over 40 tests.

I do not want to ditch successful tests.

It would be great to have a quick way to write the results into a GUI, so I can see all without scrolling.

For example when I run the script a GUI pops up with all results side by side.

Comment: This feels a bit broad; have you tried `tkinter` or anything of that sort?

Comment: have you consider using noise or pytest modules for testing? you can get test results to html/xml output

Comment: Long time ago since I've tkinter. Thought there might be a quicker solution. I could write the console output into a file and then use the file with tkinter. Feels like a lot of setup for such a minor feature.

Comment: @Roman a GUI is never a minor feature.

Comment: PyCharm has a built in view for visualising test results if you are using a known framework. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-and-exploring-test-results.html

Comment: Thanks @all for the comments. I check the built in feature